# Creating powershell classes that inherit from Excel Outlook COM

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, outlook

My ultimate goal is to setup a service using Powershell, either as a script or executable, that can interact with Outlook and Excel by way of using custom classes. While I could implement the custom class so that code outside the class can instantiate the Excel and Outlook COM objects, and subsequently instantiate the custom class and fill its properties, I'd like to have the class inherit from the COM objects themselves in order to create custom methods that can perform the work of filling the properties as soon as the custom class is instantiated (via initialize method) and perform other error checking and such. Is this possible? or advisable? I've looked online and here as well and have not found anything that remotely resembles what I'd like to do.

The task is updating an excel workbook from outlook inbox which receives similarly formatted emails where only the subject line contains the information to be updated.

Comment: [Integrating Microsoft Excel with PowerShell](https://www.petri.com/export-to-excel-with-powershell) and [Powershell Script to create new Outlook Meeting](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aa9ef119-b309-48bd-84fe-4847d0117c26/powershell-script-to-create-new-outlook-meeting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot inherit from or extended a COM object.

Comment: thank you for your answer. A quick follow-up. If I can't inherit from the COM object, could I at least use the COM object inside the class to more or less achieve the same object of not having to use code outside of the class or in the main script to perform the procedures needed to fill in the property values?

Comment: Of course, you can expose a class that exposes to the outside world the methods you want, but uses the Outlook.Application object internally. Hard to be more precise without knowing more about what your code is supposed to do.